# Angular: one shared module for generic components vs single component modules

Tags: angular

Since different sources provide some contradicting information I'm struggling to understand which is best practice:

a. having SharedModule for different components, directives, and pipes that are used among several feature modules (as described here: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module).

b. having a module for each component, directive or pipe the same way `Angular Material` structured their components/directives, and it also resembles the new standalone component feature in Angular v14. (and if they have a logical relation maybe import some of these modules to a single shared module).

Comment: I believe the purpose of splitting things into modules is so they can be lazy loaded as needed, as opposed to loading everything up front. So option a) is simpler, but option b) has performance gains. Material does it so you don't need to load their entire library to use one component.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton I agree,that's why I think that having a bunch of unnecessary components and directives imported to several feature modules that doesn't use all of them is bad practice in an applications that's growing and may eventually have a really large SharedModule.
Just want to be sure I'm not missing anything and what is considered best practice :)